# How to add one-to-many objects to the parent object using ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following code base for has_many relation in ActiveRecord rails:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
end  

class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :bar
end
```

How do i add FooBar entries to Foo during creation.
This is my code as follows:

```
@foo = Foo.create(params[:foo])
bars = params[:bars] # bars in a array of string format
bar_ids = bars.collect{|b| b.to_i}

@foo.foo_bars << bar_ids
@foo.save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
@foo = Foo.create(params[:foo])
@foo.foo_bars << params[:bars].map {|s| FooBar.new(:bar_id => s.to_i)}  
@foo.save
```

It build a new `FooBar` instance of each id in the `params[:bars]` collection. The final `save` will create both the `@foo` and the `FooBar`. See [doc here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) for help on associations.

For edition:

```
@foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
@foo.foo_bars = params[:bars].map {|s| @foo.foo_bars.where(:bar_id => s.to_i).first_or_initialize }
```

Comment: @diya I've update my answer for edition; the idea is to find the existing `FooBar` if `bar_id` matches, or create new ones.

Comment: Will the above code handle removal of foo_bars if they are unselected and new ones selected.

Comment: Yeap, the `=` operator does that.

Comment: The "=" operator only handling the addition of check_boxes while Update but it does not seems to work the removal of foo_bars.