# How to handle removal of entries in a multi select check box are used

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is in continuation to the question which was raised here

[How to add one-to-many objects to the parent object using ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210364/how-to-add-one-to-many-objects-to-the-parent-object-using-activerecord)

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foo_bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
end  

class FooBar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :bar
end
```

How to handle removal of entries in a multi select check box are used to represent one-to-many entities. I am able to add or update entries, but removal seems to fail since **foo_id** seems to be empty and the query seems to be updating instead of delete.

**EDIT** :

I tried with @charlysisto suggestion using the following code

My Controller code is as follows :

```
  class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :foo_bars
    has_many :bars, :through => :foo_bars
  end

   def edit
    @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
    @sites = Site.where(company_id: @current_user.company_id).all
   end

  def update
    @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])

    if @foo.update_attributes(params[:foo])
      flash[:notice] = "Foo was successfully updated"
      redirect_to foos_path
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
   end
```

View code is as follows :

```
<% @bars.each do |bar| %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'bar_ids[]', bar.id %>
    <%= bar.name %>
<% end %>
```

So I tried with these changes, but still foo_bars doesn't seem to reflect the changes if I removed a record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's missing in your associations is this :

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars, :through => :foo_bars
end
```

... the has_many (or has_many :through) macro gives you a truck load of methods including `bar_ids` and `bar_ids= [...]`

So all you need to do in your views/controller is :

```
# edit.html.haml which will send an array of bar_ids
=f.select :bar_ids, Bar.all.map {|b| [b.name, b.id]}, {}, :multiple => true

# foo_controller
@foo.update_attributes(params[:foo])
```

And that's it! No need to manually set or delete the associations in FooController#update...

Comment: Thanks for the response ! Actually I have foo_bars and not bars, not sure if the logic still holds good. Since I will have to list many bars and the user will either select or de-select a certain bar which is supposed to create foo_bars. My data model is present in the previous ticket.

Comment: See my update (basically you must use has_many through) and rails takes care of the rest (again using bar_ids= directly, foo_bar is just a join table & is transparent to you).

Comment: foo_bars doesn't seem to reflect the changes if I removed a record.

Comment: Did you try with `select :bar_ids...` ? whats params does your controller receive with the checkbox version of the form.

Comment: Processing by FooController#update as HTML  
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"token", "foo"=>{"name"=>"Foo Test 1", "bars"=>["3", "5", "6"], "id"=>"1"}

Comment: Now i tried with f.select, it works fine but why con't with checkboxes ?

Comment: Checkbox doesn't submit the ones that aren't checked. You'll find a good explanation and solution here : http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes. (unfortunately the revised version is not free)